# excel separate cell value into rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel problem which i am not sure it can be solved.

I want to change this excel format

[image]

To this format:

[image]

Possible?

Terry

Comment: Have you tried the "text to columns function" in the data menu?

Comment: Yes. I have tried but its not what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible to do. 
You have to make use of VBA though if you dont want to do them manually.

Step one : Use text to columns to seperate the values in column C

```
 Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Step Two : Paste it into another sheet but transpose it

```
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

Step Three : Copy Column A and Column B into the New Sheet and Repeat it across all entries in C

There are two loops involved , one to iterate through Each Entry in c:c and the other to paste A and B till All C are filled in New sheet.

If you are not familiar with VBA you can always record a Macro and try to make it Dynamic so that the ranges and loops are adjusted to your data.

If your data is not that big and you dont want to use VBA 
You can checkout Split String and Transpose functions.

[Split String](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68)

[Transpose](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027)

Answer (score 0):

first select C2 cell and go to data tab
[text to columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4iHR.png)

so copy all cells and paste special as follows:
[paste special ... transpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIi14.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
Sub main()
    Dim users As Variant

    users = Split(Replace(Range("C2"), " ", ""), ",")
    Range("A2:B2").Resize(UBound(users) + 1).Value = Range("A2:B2").Value
    Range("C2").Resize(UBound(users) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(users)
End Sub
```

Comment: @xingtan, I see you keep asking and getting good answers but never mark them as accepted. As per this site rules (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)) you have to _click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in_. Thank you!